# shopware Setting up a hosting

Tags: php, hosting, shopware

I need to download shopware 5.2 to the server

Try:

1) Files uploaded to the server

2) DB uploaded to the server

3) updated `config.php`

When I go to the site `http://my_site_on_hosting.com`, I get 301 Moved Permanently to `http://shopware.loc`

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login into backend and change the url of the shop to the domain of your hosting.